# How to bookmark message using botframework

Tags: botframework

I'm using Microsoft bot framework to create a bot and using direct channel to incorporate into web application.During the conversation,I need to bookmark or like the message or response from the bot.

Comment: Can you please clarify "bookmark" or "like"? If you are talking about saving the result for later use. Any serializable property you have in the same dialog will stay there for the whole dialog session. If not serializable, you are likely to get into a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Bot Framework doesn't implement this functionailty in SDKs. You can leverage middleware feature to implement it your self.

General idea is, you can save every activity message pairs with your users. And create a [global message handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-global-handlers) for `mark` or `like` or detect every message in middleware to check wether user said `mark` or `like`. When you can marked the `mard` tag for the last message you saved previously.

For the sample of Middleware usage, refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-Middleware for C# and https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/capability-middlewareLogging for Node.js.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the **IActivityLogger** which is there in the **Microsoft.Bot.Builder.History** namespace to store/bookmark the IMessageActivity message into a DB or a cache.

**IActivityLogger** will [**intercept**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-middleware) every message from your dialog which implements IDialog interface.

This is for intercepting every message that is sent and recieved to-fro from the user and the bot.

**1) For Dialogs implementing the IDialog interface:**

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.History;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DemoBot.Dialogs
{
    public class Logger : IActivityLogger
    {

        private readonly IMongoClient client;
        private readonly IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection;
        public Logger()
        {
            client = new MongoClient();
            collection = client.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("botLog");
        }
        public Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
        {
            IMessageActivity msgToBeLogged = activity.AsMessageActivity();

            BsonDocument objectToBeLogged = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "messageText", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.Text) },
                { "timeStamp", new BsonDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(msgToBeLogged.Timestamp)) },
                { "recipientId", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.Recipient.Id) },
                { "fromId", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.From.Id) },
                { "conversationId", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.Conversation.Id) },
                { "fromName", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.From.Name) },
                { "toName", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.Recipient.Name) },
                { "channnel", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.ChannelId) },
                { "serviceUrl",new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.ServiceUrl) },
                { "locale", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.Locale)}
            };

            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                LogIntoDB(objectToBeLogged);
            });
        }

        public void LogIntoDB(BsonDocument activityDetails)
        {
            collection.InsertOne(activityDetails);
        }
    }
}
```

2) **For Dialogs that inherit the LuisDialog** class, write the logging code in the DispatchToIntentHandler method, as it will the incoming message will pass through that method to resolve into the appropriate handler:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DemoBot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
    {
        public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => { context.Wait(MessageReceived); });
        }

        protected override Task DispatchToIntentHandler(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item, IntentRecommendation bestIntent, LuisResult result)
        {
            IMessageActivity msgToBeLogged = context.MakeMessage();

            BsonDocument objectToBeLogged = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "messageText", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.Text) },
                { "timeStamp", new BsonDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(msgToBeLogged.Timestamp)) },
                { "recipientId", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.Recipient.Id) },
                { "fromId", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.From.Id) },
                { "conversationId", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.Conversation.Id) },
                { "fromName", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.From.Name) },
                { "toName", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.Recipient.Name) },
                { "channnel", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.ChannelId) },
                { "serviceUrl",new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.ServiceUrl) },
                { "locale", new BsonString(msgToBeLogged.Locale)}
            };

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                LogIntoDB(objectToBeLogged);
            });

            return base.DispatchToIntentHandler(context, item, bestIntent, result);
        }

        public void LogIntoDB(BsonDocument activityDetails)
        {
            collection.InsertOne(activityDetails);
        }


        public Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                context.Wait(MessageReceived);
            });   
        }

    }
}
```

For Logging I'm using MongoDB, but you can use SQL Server also if you wish.

And lastly inject the dependencies in your global.asax.cs file using Autofac IoC.

```
using Autofac;
using DemoBot.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace DemoBot
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterType<Logger>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();
            });

            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
}
```